# How to create CSS border corners around text

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to put corner borders around responsive text.

Screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve using green corners: 
[image]
[Here](https://pintsandpots.com/) is the domain of where the text resides.

```
div {
position: relative;
width: 380px;
height: 0px;
margin: 6px;
```

}

```
div:after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    border-top: 4px solid green;
    border-right: 4px solid green;
}
a p:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -70px;
    left: -6px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
    border-left: 4px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

h1:before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #9b59b6;
  border-top: 3px solid #9b59b6;
}

h1:after {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEXT</h1>
```

Absolute positioning and `height & width` of `before` and `after` are the key.

Comment: You rock! Wow, thank you so very much. :)

Answer (score -1):

Change `a p:before` to `div:before` and that should get you on the right path.